# Flows in Visualforce pages - odd error message

Tags: visualforce, visual-workflow

I have a Visualforce page that looks like this (simplified a bit)

```
<apex:page controller="ManageSiteScholarCtrlr" >
    <apex:form id="ManageSiteScholarFrm">
...
    <apex:pageBlockSection >
    <apex:pageBlockTable >
```

When I add the following below the lines listed above:

```
<apex:column headerValue="remove">
<flow:interview name="RemoveScholars">
    <apex:param name="ScholarProgramID" value="{!sl.ScholarProg.ID}"/>
</flow:interview>  
</apex:column>
```

I get the following error in the Developer Console:

> 'apex:form component cannot be nested within form tags'

As far as I can tell, the lines in question have nothing to do with "apex:form".  What is the Developer Console really complaining about here?  Trying to use a flow inside a page block?  Trying to use a flow inside a column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a flow:interview is basically an embedded Visualforce page, it provides its own form. You can't have an apex:form inside of another apex:form, so it's complaining about it. You'll need to move the interview outside of your other form. I don't know of another workaround for this.

This page I mocked up also gives the same compilation error:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <flow:interview name="TESTFLOW" interview="{!myFlow}" finishlocation="{!Contact.Id}" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Seeing as how practically as simple as you can strip it down, this simply proves that flow:interview is considered an apex:form for purposes of compilation.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up.  It would be helpful for users new to flows if the error message weren't quite so generic.

Comment: @Jagular I agree. This isn't even in the documentation.